# PHP making a protected property public at runtime

Tags: php, reflection, public, protected

Problem: I don't want to expose `$myProperty`, that is it shouldn't be `public`, but I need it to be `public` just for `__toString()`:

```php
class A
{
    protected $myProperty;

    public function __toString()
    {
        return json_encode($this);
    }
}
```

I know that `ReflectionProperty` class has a method named `setAccessible()`, but how I'm supposed to use it before returning the string?

**EDIT**: as per comments, I need compatibility with PHP 5.3.x, that is no `JSonSerializable` class.

Comment: Psst: http://php.net/JsonSerializable

Comment: I'd better implement [`JsonSerializable`](http://php.net/manual/en/jsonserializable.jsonserialize.php) interface in order to state clearly which fields will be serialized, and which not.

Comment: I'd have to say that `setAccessible()` probably falls under the category of "evil magic that you should never use". It's interesting, but should never be necessary in production code.

Comment: @moonwave99 of course, BUT I need compatibility with 5.3.x.

Comment: @gremo well that's basically the same - you don't implement the interface, and you call the method explicitly when you need it ^^

Comment: @duskwuff can you explain better with it's evil? Reflection is evil for you?

Comment: Anyway my fav solution is to rely on [annotations](https://github.com/schmittjoh/metadata) when serializing: you take advantage of reflection but you don't mess with hardcoding inside the class itself.

Comment: @Gremo: It's "evil" in that it breaks the contract of field protection. If the field isn't actually private, don't make it private. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per PHP 5.3 use [`get_object_vars`](http://php.net/get_object_vars) inside the `__toString()` method:

```
public function __toString()
{
    return json_encode(get_object_vars($this));
}
```

Usage [Demo](http://eval.in/4897):

```
class A
{
    protected $myProperty = 'hello';

    public function __toString()
    {
        return json_encode(get_object_vars($this));
    }
}

echo new A;
```

Output:

```
{"myProperty":"hello"}
```

Tip: Create the [`JsonSerializable`](http://php.net/JsonSerializable) interface your own and implement the `jsonSerialize()` method your own to be upwards compatible. Call the function when you need it and/or call it inside `__toString()`:

```
public function __toString()
{
    return json_encode($this->jsonSerialize());
}
```

Comment: Interesting... this will work because the protected property is in the scope, right?

Comment: Exactly. Will also give private properties. As well as with `(array) $this` but that one has unwanted side-effects so `get_object_vars` is better.

Comment: Curious, is `(object)` cast here necessary?

Comment: @zerkms: technically not, because `json_encode` will it encode as json object because of non-numeric keys. Edited. (nice spot, thx)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply build a PHP `stdClass` object and then serialize it to JSON, since when you deserialize from JSON, that is exactly what you get anyway.

Maybe something like this:

```
public function __toString() {
   $return = new stdClass();
   $properties = get_object_vars($this);
   foreach ($properties as $key => $value) {
       $return->$key = $value;
   }
   return json_encode($return);
}
```